# InverseFunction: how can I extract the function inside?

Tags: functions, function-construction

This is probably a trivial question. But I could not find an answer.

Given the explicit expression for `ft` in te assignment

```
ft = InverseFunction[f[#] &][t];
```

I would like to invert this, i.e. to get the function `t[f[x]]`. Of course I can copy the expression `f[#]&` and paste it into the right hand side of the assignment

```
t[x_] = f[#]& [x];
```

But I think there should be a valid Mathematica method to do the extraction.

The `FullForm[]` of `ft` shows a presumed `List[]` which, however, is a strange contruct which only lets me extract the argument `t` as its first element.

Example (I write it in Latex just to save space)

$ft = \text{InverseFunction}\left[-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{2 \text{$\#$1}^2}{\sqrt{4 w+1}-1}+1} \sqrt{1-\frac{2 \text{$\#$1}^2}{\sqrt{4 w+1}+1}} F\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 w+1}-1}} \text{$\#$1}\right)|\frac{1-\sqrt{4 w+1}}{\sqrt{4 w+1}+1}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 w+1}-1}} \sqrt{-\text{$\#$1}^4+\text{$\#$1}^2+w}}\&\right][t]$

I wish to extract the expression in square brackets.

Taking the compact solution 2 from the answer of xzczd we find

```
tx = ft[[0, 1]][x]
```

$-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{2 x^2}{\sqrt{4 w+1}-1}+1} \sqrt{1-\frac{2 x^2}{\sqrt{4 w+1}+1}} F\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 w+1}-1}} x\right)|\frac{1-\sqrt{4 w+1}}{\sqrt{4 w+1}+1}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 w+1}-1}} \sqrt{w-x^4+x^2}}$

Comment: Do you mean something like: `t = InverseFunction@Head@ft`, or `t = InverseFunction@Function[t, #] &@ft`, or `t = ft[[0, 1]]`?

Comment: Have you noticed what happens when you do `InverseFunction[InverseFunction[f]]`?

Comment: Well, actually your _@name_ syntax is wrong, there shouldn't be any white spaces between @ and the name, or it won't trigger a notification :)

Comment: This question would be more clear if you gave a specific example and the expected result.

Comment: @J. M.: Thanks, I have done this first, of course. But it is returned unevaluated, at least in my case of a complicated function f

Comment: @xzczd : thanks, I "knew" that my question was trivial ... ;-)  And thanks for the hint to the correct sntax of addressing a user here. (I have now repeated my comments in the correct syntax).

Answer (score 4):

OK, let me extend the comment into an answer. If `ft` still contains `InverseFunction`, your goal can be achieved by

```
(* Solution 1 *)
tf = First@Head@ft
(* Solution 2 *)
tf = ft[[0, 1]]
(* Solution 3 *)
tf = InverseFunction@Head@ft
(* Solution 4 *)
tf = InverseFunction@ft[[0]]
(* Solution 5 *)
tf = InverseFunction@Function[t, #] &@ft
```

*Solution 5* should also work for the cases that `ft` no longer contains `InverseFunction`.